# Take a photo with the standard android app and store in db

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

In my android application I need to call the standard photo app, take a photo and store it in the sqlite database the device.

This is my handler for the button to start the intent

```
private Uri fileUri;
private File file;
private ImageView foto;

public void fotoHandler(View view) {
    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    file = FileUtilities.getOutputMediaFile();
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file); // create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

This is the resulthandler

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                         fileUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         try {
             Bitmap bitmap =  MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), fileUri);
             file.delete();
             foto.setImageBitmap(laatsteFoto);
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "File " + fileUri.toString() + " can't be found !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "File " + fileUri.toString() + " can't be read !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         // User cancelled the image capture
     } else 
         Toast.makeText(this, "Error during retrieving photo from camera !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

It works fine on my Acer A100 with ICS, but gives problems on my Samsung Galaxy S2 with ICS.

```
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {be.lengo.autikoken/be.lengo.autikoken.IngredientWijzigen}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {be.lengo.autikoken/be.lengo.autikoken.IngredientWijzigen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1997)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3362)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1162)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {be.lengo.autikoken/be.lengo.autikoken.IngredientWijzigen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2991)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    ... 13 more
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at be.lengo.autikoken.IngredientWijzigen.onActivityResult(IngredientWijzigen.java:233)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4654)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2987)
10-24 08:44:05.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19861):    ... 14 more
```

Log when I comment the toast with the result

```
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {be.lengo.autikoken/be.lengo.autikoken.IngredientWijzigen}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {be.lengo.autikoken/be.lengo.autikoken.IngredientWijzigen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1997)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3362)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1162)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {be.lengo.autikoken/be.lengo.autikoken.IngredientWijzigen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2991)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    ... 13 more
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:361)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:715)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at be.lengo.autikoken.IngredientWijzigen.onActivityResult(IngredientWijzigen.java:236)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4654)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2987)
10-24 09:27:06.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21849):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Which is line 233 from your onActivityResult() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug on Samsung Galaxy S2 if your activity is supposed to run only in portrait mode. What happens is you start the camera, it takes the picture and, when returning,  starts your activity in landscape first than, within 1 second, it rotates to portrait. Make sure you properly save all your variables in the activity using onSaveInstanceState and restoring in onCreate. This happened to me as I was not saving them and that phone was rotating the activity.

Comment: Another reason to upgrade to a Galaxy S3 ;-)

Comment: This is amazing information, I have been debugging this for hours. Do you have a link for more information?

Comment: No sorry, it's just something it happened to me. Unfortunately that's not even the only device who does it wrong. LG 4X HD has the same issue and local variables should be always saved/restored even if the screen is not supposed to switch between landscape and portrait.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply (and the wisdom of your experience!). Will tackle full state management even for those Activities I thought would never re-orient.

Answer (score 0):

The fileUri may be null. Try to initialize it properly.